# Add time units to a date | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the date of the day, month, and year from a certain date + five days later.

This is my code:

```
import datetime

day = datetime.datetime(2018,3,27).strftime("%d")
month = datetime.datetime(2018,3,27).strftime("%m")
year = datetime.datetime(2018,3,27).strftime("%Y")

day += datetime.timedelta(days=5)
month += datetime.timedelta(days=5)
year += datetime.timedelta(days=5)

print (day)
print (month)
print (year)
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta
```

I tried to convert with str () but then 2019 I got 20195.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you bothering to calculate timedeltas for day, month, and year separately?  Just do it all at once.

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2018,3,27)
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days=5)

print (end.day)
print (end.month)
print (end.year)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are making it a little more complicated than it needs to be :P.

If you just simplify your code a bit and it works fine.

```
import datetime

my_date = datetime.datetime(2018,3,27) + datetime.timedelta(days=5)

print (my_date)
```

When ran

```
2018-04-01 00:00:00
```

If you want the 3 values on different lines like your question you can do something like this

```
my_date.strftime('%d\n%m\n%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wear something like that.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

today = datetime.now()
print(today)
     2019-05-02 15:46:58.262000

today_plus_five_days = today + timedelta(days = 5)
print(today_plus_five_days)
    2019-05-07 15:46:58.262000
```